# Styling hyperlinks on click-javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am trying something. I have changed the styling say background color of each link  to one different color after a link is clicked but the problem is:
I want to get the original style of link when the other link is clicked.

The HTML code is:

```
<a href="#/tab1.html" onclick="hyper1()" class="one" id="link1">Tab1</a>
<a href="#/tab2.html" onclick="hyper2()" class="two" id="link2">Tab2</a>
```

CSS Code:

```
a.one{
     left:200px;
}

a.two{
     left:260px;
}

a:link{
     color:white;
     top:20px;
     position: absolute;
     font-weight:bold;
     text-align:center;
     padding:4px;
     text-decoration:none;
}

a:visited{
     font-weight:bold;
     color:#cccccc;
}
a:hover,a:active{
     background-color:rgb(75, 110, 201);
     width: 50px;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
   function hyper1() {
      var x = document.getElementById("link1");
      x.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(75, 110, 201)";
      x.style.width="50px";
   }

   function hyper2(){
      var y=document.getElementById("link2");
      y.style.backgroundColor="rgb(75, 110, 201)";
      y.style.width="50px";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use `:active` pseudo for this purpose?

Comment: I tried that but it is not working. In my CSS i have used a:active, it is working fine but when i clicked on another link, it still shows me the background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code: http://jsfiddle.net/F6kbw/32/
let me know if u have any issues

```
function hyper1(element) {
   var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
   for (var i = 0;i < x.length;i++) { 
    x[i].style.backgroundColor="white";
   }
   element.style.backgroundColor="rgb(75, 110, 201)";
```

}

Comment: It worked but I have one issue, if there are many links then when I clicked on any link then all other links loose the property of mouseover and no background.

Comment: yes i checked it, i have done it. Here before clicking on any tab hover works and no background is shown. But once we click on any tab, hover doesn't work plus the background appears on every other tab.

Comment: I didn't get you.Can u explain clearly? I have tested it background is working.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
// get all links with class .colored_links
var allMyLinks = $(".colored_links");

    allMyLinks.click(function(){

        // regular link color
        var linkRegularColor = "#000000"
        // clicked link color
        var linkClicColor = "#ffffff"

        // set color to all link with class ".colored_links" black color
        allMyLinks.css("color",linkRegularColor);

        // set color of clicked link to white
        $(this).css("color",linkClicColor);

    });
```

not sure, but you can try
JS:

```
var allMyLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".colored_links");

for(var i=0;i<allMyLinks.length;i++){
  allMyLinks[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}

var myFunction = function() {

  for(var i=0;i<allMyLinks.length;i++){
    allMyLinks[i].style.color = "#000000";
  }
  this.style.color = "#ffffff";

};
```

Comment: to my shame, I was too relaxed with jquery, and begin to forget pure js). but logic is same: get all links, set them one color, and after that set color to clicked one